# Como pegar data atual, e colocar em um insert?

Tags: php

Como posso fazer para pegar a data atual do servidor e colocar na minha query para enviar para o banco? Não tenho a minima ideia de como posso pegar a hora atual e colocar em uma variável para mandar para o banco, obrigado.

Comment: Podes fazer isso na linguagem do banco. Se for MySQL podes usar `NOW()`. Já testaste isso? Em PHP há várias maneiras, uma delas `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Comment: NOW() pega data e hora? Não testei

Comment: Exato, tipo `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:DD`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW() CAMINHO

Quando estou usando o NOW no insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso na linguagem do banco.
Se for MySQL podes usar `NOW()` que dá `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:DD` ou seja, data e hora.

Em PHP há várias maneiras, uma delas `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`, outra é

```
$now = new DateTime();
$datetime = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW() in ***CAMINHO***

Comment: Quando eu uso o NOW no insert

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo Você se confundiu :) ... `NOW` não é uma função PHP é uma função mysql, ou seja deve ser uma string no PHP dentro da query e não uma chamada de função, algo como `"INSERT INTO soFoo (first,last,minhadata) VALUES (0,1,Now())"`

Comment: Obrigado estava colocando no lugar errado mesmo.